# CakePHP. Multiple Forms per page

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have website with few short News , to every News we can write a comment via Form. And there my problem occur.
When i fill my fields in one form, after pressing button, all forms are reloading without saving, and every field in every form must be filled out so they're treated like a one part how to avoid it ?

Additional info ( Info is my main modal with news, it's joined with Com modal)

index.ctp Form

```
<br><h5>Add comment:</h5><br>
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('Com'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input(__('mail',true),array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input(__('body',true),array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                <?php $this->request->data['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp(); ?>
                <?php $this->request->data['info_id'] = $info['Info']['id']; ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Add comment',true),array('class'=>'btn btn-info')); ?>
                <?php $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

controller ComsController.php

```
public function add()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $this->Infos_com->create();
        $this->request->data['Infos_com']['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp();
        $this->request->data['Infos_com']['id_infos'] = $number;
        if($this->Infos_com->save($this->request->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment is waiting for moderating',true),array('class'=>'alert alert-info'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Infos','action'=>'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Niepowodzenie dodania komentarza',true),array('class'=>'alert alert-info'));
        return TRUE;
    }}
```

and Model Com.php, i comment lines to avoid neccesity of filling every field in forms

```
class Com extends AppModel
{
public $belongsTo = array('Info');
/*public $validate = array(
    'mail'=>array(
        'requierd'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('notEmpty'),
            'message'=>'Write your email'
        )
    ),
    'body'=>array(
        'required'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('notEmpty'),
            'messages'=>'Write smth'
        )
    )
); */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access $this->request->data in a view (the data should be entered with a form, it was not submitted). You should use hidden fields to pass arguments like IP od id... Example:

`echo $this->Form->input('Infos_com.client_id', array(
    'type' => 'hidden',
    'value' => $value
    ));`

If you have multiple forms, it would be useful to separate their fields. For example:

`echo $this->Form->input('Infos_com.' . $news_id . '.body', array('label' => __('body')));`

This way you will get an array like:

`$this->request->data['Infos_com'][$news_id]['body'].`

And then you can make your logic in the model.

Comment: You're right, $this->request->data should be in controller, i already working to fix my problem, but You gave me really good tip. Thank You man

Comment: Actually, according to the CakePHP cookbook:  "By default CakeRequest is assigned to $this->request, and is available in Controllers, Views and Helpers."  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakerequest  Also, be careful using hidden fields to pass foreign keys since that is also possibly a security hole.  People could then post data to your page with any sort of id, including, say ids that don't exist, or ids they shouldn't have access to.  Like if they wrote their own page with curl or something to interact with your website.

Comment: Yep, I was wrong. It is accessible in the view with `$this->data`, and it is much better to assign additional values to the data array within the controller (before saving).