# cakephp multiple forms with same action

Tags: forms, cakephp, view, controller

I've got on my page several News, to every News we can add comment via form.
So actually I've got 3 News on my index.ctp, and under every News is a Form to comment this particular News. Problem is, when i add comment, data is taken from the last Form on the page.
I don;t really know how to diverse them.
i've red [multirecord forms](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Marcelius/2008/10/22/how-to-create-multirecord-forms) and [Multiple Forms per page](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/RabidFire/2010/06/26/multiple-forms-per-page-for-the-same-model) ( last one is connected to different actions), and i don't figure it out how to manage it.
Second problem is, i can't send $id variable through the form to controller ( $id has true value, i displayed it on index.ctp just to see )

This is my Form

```
 <?php $id = $info['Info']['id']; echo $this->Form->create('Com', array('action'=>'add',$id)); ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input(__('Com.mail',true),array('class'=>'form-control','field'=>'mail')); ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input(__('Com.body',true),array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
 <?php  echo  $this->Form->submit(__('Dodaj komentarz',true),array('class'=>'btn btn-info')); ?>
 <?php $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

and there is my controller ComsController.php

```
class ComsController extends AppController
{
   public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
   public $components = array('Session');

   public function index()
   {
       $this->set('com',  $this->Com->find('all'));
   }
   public function add($idd = NULL)
   {
       if($this->request->is('post'))
       {
           $this->Com->create();
           $this->request->data['Com']['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp(); 
           $this->request->data['Com']['info_id'] = $idd; 
           if($this->Com->save($this->request->data))
           {
               $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment added with success',true),array('class'=>'alert alert-info'));
               return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Infos','action'=>'index'));
           }
           $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to addd comment',true),array('class'=>'alert alert-info'));
           return false;

       }
       return true;
   }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP. Multiple Forms per page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982096/cakephp-multiple-forms-per-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not closing your forms

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

for the id problem you should write

```
echo $this->Form->create(
    'Com', 
    array('action'=>'add/'.$id
    )
);
```

or

```
echo $this->Form->create(
    'Com', 
    array(
        'url' => array('action'=>'add', $id)
    )
);
```

Comment: Brilliant !! Thank You, so simple, and i break my hole night changing everything.

And can You take a look, what's wrong with passing $id value to controller ? I Saw on stackoverflow that proper sending value via form is in craeting field, after action in array, like mine.

Comment: You're my hero ;), really ;) THANK YOU